# how to insert session multiple array in codeigniter from ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

**form input**

```
<form id='form'>
  <input type="text" name="nama" value="">      
  <input type="text" name="email" value="">     
  <input type="button" id='button' name="button" value="kirim">
</form>
<div id='hasil'></div>
```

**ajax sent**

```
$(document).on('click', '#button', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();       
  var data = $('#form').serializeArray();
  $.ajax({
    data : {data : data},
    url:'data/test_ajax',
    method:'post',
    success:function (data_ajax){
      console.log(data_ajax);
    }
  });
});
```

**sent to data/test_ajax**

```
public function test_ajax(){
    $data = $this->input->post('data');

    $get_session = $this->session->userdata('data');
    for ($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++) { 
        if ($get_session[$i]=="") {
            $dat['data'][$i]['nama'] = $data[0]['value'];
            $dat['data'][$i]['email'] = $data[1]['value'];
            $set_session = $this->session->set_userdata($dat);
            break;
        }
    }

    $get_session = $this->session->userdata('data');
    print_r($get_session);
}
```

**how to insert to session with `codeigniter` every adding data from `ajax`,
result like as :**

> [0] => Array
>   (
>   [nama] => test
>   [email] => test
>   )
>
> [1] => Array
>   (
>   [nama] => testtt
>   [email] => testttt
>   )
>
> [2] => Array
>   (
>   [nama] => aaa
>   [email] => aaaaa
>   )
>
> [3] => Array
>   (
>   [nama] => aa
>   [email] => sdfaaaaasdfdsf
>   )

Comment: You check actual session data, but overwrite it with new values

Comment: yes, why overwrite it new values in new row array ? @bato3

Comment: You may want to remove the name attribute on your button, because I don't think you want/need  `$_POST['button]='kirim'`

Answer (score 0):

I dont ktow how works codeinteger get/set-userdata, but try this

```
$get_session = $this->session->userdata('data');
$get_session[] = Array('nama'=>$data[0]['value'], 'email' => $data[1]['value']);
$set_session = $this->session->set_userdata('data',$get_session);
```

OT safest way to pass data to script would be

```
var datastring = $("#form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "your url.php",
        data: datastring,
        success: function(data) {
             alert('Data send');
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Maxthinks this seems like the correct answer.  If you are satisfied please award it the green tick so that your question is removed from the unanswered questions list.  If this answer is not quite doing what you need, please leave a comment for bato3.